Quelle est la différence entre le bruissage et le repassage d'étoffes ?
Wiktionary définit le bruissage comme suit : « (Vieilli) Chauffage d’une étoffe à la vapeur pour l’amollir. » (lien)
Wikipédia ne connaît même pas le bruissage, je n'y retrouve aucune référence.
L'Académie 9e édition définit le bruissage comme l'action de bruir, et définit bruir comme suit : « Passer une pièce d'étoffe à la vapeur afin de l'assouplir. » (lien)
À partir de ces définitions, il me semble que le bruissage pourrait être fait avec un fer à vapeur et, du coup, je ne saisis pas bien la différence de sens entre bruissage et repassage...

Jamais entendu bruissage.

Le repassage n'implique pas forcément l'utilisation de la vapeur, on a le choix avec les fers à repasser actuels d'utiliser la vapeur ou de ne pas l'utiliser.
Bruir vient du francique brojan « brûler, roussir, échauder». Ce mot est apparenté aux mots allemand brühen (échauder), Brei (bouillie), Brodem (vapeur chaude). Le sens de « brûler, griller » s'est spécialisé en parlant de l'action du soleil sur les plantes.
C'est à partir de 1751 que le mot a signifié « imbiber de vapeur des étoffes que l'on veut amollir ».  Bruissage, substantif formé à partir de buire, apparait en même temps. C'est resté un mot technique¹ et il n'est plus employé de nos jours, je pense même qu'il est inconnu connu dans le repassage industriel.
Le bruissage se faisait à la main, c'est la main qui aspergeait, imbibait le tissu de vapeur chaude (éventuellement avec un instrument, mais indépendant du fer à repasser). Les premiers fers électriques ont commencé à être  commercialisés dans la première partie du 20ᵉ siècle et ce n'est que dans la deuxième moitié du 20ᵉ siècle que le fer à vapeur intégrée s'est répandu. À partir du moment où il a suffit d'appuyer sur un bouton de son fer pour ramollir la pièce à repasser, plus besoin d'asperger la pièce d'eau pour la ramollir. Je suppose que c'est pour cette raison que le terme de « bruissage » a cessé d'être utilisé.
Et de toute façon le bruissage était une action séparée du repassage au sens strict (lissage au moyen d'un fer chaud) : dans un premier temps on bruissait l'étoffe, dans un deuxième temps on la repassait.

 ¹ Renseignements étymologiques et lexicaux adaptés du Dictionnaire historique en langue française 

Le bruissage était aussi un procédé industriel utilisé au XIXème siécle dans le traitement de la laine. Après le "tortillonage", le bruissage (passage à la vapeur) permettait d'allonger et redresser les brins de laine.

@Graffito, Tout à fait, le bruissage de la laine était une des étapes de la préparation de la laine peignée.  Le fait de bruisser est indépendant du fait de repasser.

Je note en passant qu'il y a aussi des petits défroisseurs [à] vapeur...
